# Infinite loop in Unity when run pathfinding code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to make enemy units pathfind to area in which they can attack the player base in my turn based game.
When I end a turn to call `DoActions()` Unity eats up my CPU and stop respond so I assume I wrote a infinite loop.
However I cannot find where the problem is in the scripts I used for this.

```
public class Pathfinding : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static List<Vector2> FindPath(Vector2 start, Vector2 goal, Unit unit)
    {
        PriorityQueue<double, Vector2> frontier = new PriorityQueue<double, Vector2>();
        Vector2 current;
        frontier.Enqueue(0, start);
        Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2> from = new Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2>();
        Dictionary<Vector2, double> cost_so_far = new Dictionary<Vector2, double>();
        cost_so_far[start] = 0;
        while (!frontier.IsEmpty)
        {
            current = frontier.Dequeue().Value;
            if (current == goal)
                break;
            foreach(Vector2 next in GetNeighborsCoor(current))
            {
                if (next.x < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(0) && next.y < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(1) && Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(next) == null)
                {
                    double cost = cost_so_far[current] + GetMoveCost(next, unit);
                    if (!from.ContainsKey(next))
                    {
                        cost_so_far[next] = cost;
                        frontier.Enqueue(cost, next);
                        from[next] = current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        current = goal;
        List<Vector2> path = new List<Vector2>();
        while(current != start)
        {
            path.Add(current);
            current = from[current];
        }
        path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }
    public static List<Vector2> FindPathToArea(Vector2 start, List<Vector2> area, Unit unit)
    {
        PriorityQueue<double, Vector2> frontier = new PriorityQueue<double, Vector2>();
        Vector2 current;
        Vector2 goal = Vector2.negativeInfinity;
        frontier.Enqueue(0, start);
        Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2> from = new Dictionary<Vector2, Vector2>();
        Dictionary<Vector2, double> cost_so_far = new Dictionary<Vector2, double>();
        cost_so_far[start] = 0;
        while (!frontier.IsEmpty)
        {
            current = frontier.Dequeue().Value;
            if (area.Contains(current))
            {
                goal = current;
                break;
            }
            foreach(Vector2 next in GetNeighborsCoor(current))
            {
                if (next.x < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(0) && next.y < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(1) && Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(next) == null)
                {
                    double cost = cost_so_far[current] + GetMoveCost(next, unit);
                    if (!from.ContainsKey(next))
                    {
                        cost_so_far[next] = cost;
                        frontier.Enqueue(cost, next);
                        from[next] = current;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        current = goal;
        List<Vector2> path = new List<Vector2>();
        while(current != start)
        {
            path.Add(current);
            current = from[current];
        }
        path.Add(start);
        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }
    public static List<Vector2> GetNeighborsCoor(Vector2 coor)
    {
        List<Vector2> neighborsCoor = new List<Vector2>();
        neighborsCoor.Add(new Vector2(coor.x + 1, coor.y));
        neighborsCoor.Add(new Vector2(coor.x - 1, coor.y));
        neighborsCoor.Add(new Vector2(coor.x, coor.y + 1));
        neighborsCoor.Add(new Vector2(coor.x, coor.y - 1));
        return neighborsCoor;
    }
    public static double GetMoveCost(Vector2 coor, Unit unit)
    {
        double cost = 0;
        Building building = Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(coor);
        if(building == null)
        {
            cost = unit.apt / unit.speed;
        }
        else
        {
            cost = building.HP / unit.atk;
        }
        return cost;
    }
    public static Vector3 TransformCoor(Vector2 coor)
    {
        Vector3 position = Tile.tilemap[(int)coor.x, (int)coor.y].gameObject.transform.position;
        position.x = -1;
        return position;
    }
    public static List<Vector2> FindAreaToAttackFrom(Vector2 target, double range)
    {
        List<Vector2> area = new List<Vector2>();
        for (int x = 0; x < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Tile.tilemap.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Vector2 current = new Vector2(x, y);
                if (Vector2.Distance(target, current) <= range)
                {
                    if(Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(current) == null && Unit.FindUnitAtCoor(current))
                    {
                        if(EnemyAI.CheckLineOfSight(current, target, 1, out List<Building> obstacles))
                        {
                            area.Add(current);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return area;
    }
}
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Turn.OnTurnEnded += DoActions;
    }

    public void DoActions()
    {
        Building playerBase = Building.GetBaseOfOwner(0);
        foreach (Unit unit in Unit.myUnits)
        {
            if(unit.owner != 0 && unit.action != 0)
            {
                if(unit.range >= Vector2.Distance(playerBase.coor, unit.coor))
                {
                    bool clearLOS = CheckLineOfSight(unit.coor, playerBase.coor, 1, out List<Building> obstacles);
                    if (clearLOS)
                    {
                        playerBase.HP -= unit.atk * unit.action;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obstacles[0].HP -= unit.atk * unit.action;
                    }
                    unit.action = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(unit.action != 0)
                    {
                        WalkPath(Pathfinding.FindPathToArea(unit.coor, Pathfinding.FindAreaToAttackFrom(playerBase.coor, unit.range), unit), unit);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void WalkPath(List<Vector2> path, Unit unit)
    {
        for (int step = 0; step <= unit.speed;)
        {
            if (Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(path[step]) == null)
            {
                if (step == unit.speed)
                {
                    Unit.MoveUnit(unit, path[step]);
                    unit.action -= 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    step++;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Building building = Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(path[step]);
                if (CheckLineOfSight(unit.coor, path[step], 1, out List<Building> obstacles))
                {
                    building.HP -= unit.atk * unit.action;
                    unit.action = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Unit.MoveUnit(unit, path[step - 1]);
                    unit.action -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool CheckLineOfSight(Vector2 from, Vector2 target, int actor, out List<Building> obstacles)
    {
        bool clear = true;
        obstacles = new List<Building>();
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(Pathfinding.TransformCoor(from), Pathfinding.TransformCoor(target) - Pathfinding.TransformCoor(from));
        if (hits != null)
        {
            foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
            {
                if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Building>() != null)
                {
                    if ((hit.transform != Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(from).gameObject) && hit.transform != Building.FindBuildingAtCoor(target).gameObject)
                    {
                        Building building = hit.transform.GetComponent<Building>();
                        if (building.owner != actor)
                        {
                            obstacles.Add(building);
                            clear = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return clear;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: Unity stop responding when I try to do that.

Comment: Debugging this is so painful, I need to close unity and reopen it everytime I try to run the code.

Comment: Well you have `while (!frontier.IsEmpty)` and within it in a loop you do `frontier.Enqueue` .. so it is quite hard to tell if and when this will ever finish ... sounds like you might possibly end up always going forth and back between two neighbors .. as said debug and go through the loop step by step .. I guess there is no other way to find out ;)

Comment: Use breakpoints inside the while loop to pause the execution to see where it gets stuck